# Universal way to fill DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to write a method to fill a datagridview in an universal way.

For example, at the moment I fill it this way:

```
var items = partRepositiory.GetAllParts().ToList();
SortableBindingList<Parts> sort = new SortableBindingList<Parts>(items);
dgEinkaufsartikel.DataSource = sort;
```

Now I want to rewrite this in a way like that:

```
public static void FillDataGridView(DataGridView dg, IEnumerable<object> data, ...)
{
     dg.DataSource = null;
     var items = data.ToList();
     SortableBindingList<Class??> sort = new SortableBindingList<Class?>(items);
     dg.DataSource = sort;
}
```

How can I do this, that I can use my classes?

Comment: You mean [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)?

Comment: Yes, right. That I can use <T>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to use a generic type parameter inside the method then the method has to be generic too, with the same generic type:

```cs
public static void FillDataGridView<T>(DataGridView dg, IEnumerable<T> data, ...) where T : class
{
     dg.DataSource = null;
     var items = data.ToList();
     var sort = new SortableBindingList<T>(items);
     dg.DataSource = sort;
}
```

Note that the second parameter uses the same type. I'm assuming that that would be required but it's not possible to say for sure based the information provided. The constraint is required because it has come to light that there is a constraint on the corresponding parameter of the `SortableBindingList<T>` class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I receive the error: The type must be a reference type in order to use it. (SortableBindingList<T>)

Comment: @Jocelyn, if `SortableBindingList` has a constraint on `T` to be a class then you need the same constraint. Add `where T : class` to the end of the method declaration.

Comment: I thought I did that??   public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T> where T : class { ...}

Comment: @Jocelyn, I said to the end of the method declaration. Yes, you have that constraint on that type so, to use that type in a method, you need the same constraint on the method.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I'll try even if I think I'm not able to do that.